# The below jsp file doesn't validate from radio button onwards

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

```js
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Validation Form</title>

<script type="text/javascript">


function validate()
{
 
 var name_str=document.my_form.name.value;
 if((name_str==null)||(name_str==""))
  {
  alert("Enter Name")
  return false
  }
 
  var pwd_str=document.my_form.pwd.value;
 if((pwd_str=="null")||(pwd_str==""))
  {
  alert("Enter Password")
  return false
  }
 
 var repwd_str=document.my_form.repwd.value;
 if((repwd_str=="null")||(repwd_str==""))
  {
  alert("ReEnter Password")
  return false
  }

 if(pwd_str!=repwd_str)
 {    
  alert("password must be same!");  
  return false  
  }  
 
 var age_str=document.my_form.age.value;
 if((age_str=="null")||(age_str==""))
  {
  alert("enter age")
  return false
  }
 
 if (isNaN(age_str))
 {
    alert("only numeric")
    return false
 }
 
 var ph_str=document.my_form.ph.value;
 if((ph_str=="null")||(ph_str==""))
 {
 alert("enter phone number")
 return false
 }

 if (isNaN(ph_str))
 {
    alert("only numeric ph")
    return false
 }

 if((ph_str.length<1)||(ph_str.length>10))
  {
  alert("Invalid length of ph")
  return false
  }
 
 var email_str=document.my_form.email.value;
 if((email_str=="null")||(email_str==""))
 {
 alert("enter email")
 return false
 }
  
 var atposition=email_str.indexOf("@");  
 var dotposition=email_str.lastIndexOf(".");  
 if (atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=x.length)
 {  
   alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address")
   return false 
 } 
 
 if ((!document.getElementById("a").checked)&&(!document.getElementById("b").checked))
  {
        alert("no button is selected");
        return false
 } 
 
 var i;
 var group1 = document.my_form.hobby;
 for (var i=0; i<group1.length; i++) {
 if (group1[i].checked)
 break;
 }

 if (i==group1.length)
 return alert("No box is checked"); 
 
 var group2 = document.getElementById.dd;
 var index_opt = group2.options[group2.selectedIndex].value;
 if(index_opt==Select)
 {
  alert("select course")
  return false
 }
 
} 

</script>


</head>
   
 <body bgcolor=aqua>
   
 <center><h3>Application Form</h3></center>

<form name="my_form" onsubmit="validate()">

<strong>Name:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</strong>
<input type=text name=name><br/>

<strong>Password:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</strong>
<input type=password name=pwd><br/>
<strong>Retype Password:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</strong>
<input type=password name=repwd><br/>

<strong>Age:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</strong>
<input type=text name=age><br/>

<strong>Phone No:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</strong>
<input tupe= text name=ph><br/>

<strong>Email:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</strong>
<input type=text name=email><br/><br/>

<strong>Sex:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</strong>
<input type= "radio" name="gender" id="a" value="Male">Male&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<input type= "radio" name="gender" id="b" value="Female">Female&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<br/><br/><br/>

<strong>Hobby:</strong>
<input type="checkbox"name= "hobby" id="1" value="singning">Singning<br/>
<input type="checkbox"name= "hobby" id="2" value="reading">Reading<br/>
<input type="checkbox"name= "hobby" id="3" value="tv">TV<br/>
<br/>

<strong>Country</strong>
<select name="mymenu" id="dd">
<option value ="Select">Select</option>
<option value ="India">India</option>
<option value ="China">China</option>
<option value ="SriLanka">SriLanka</option>
</select>


<input type="submit" value=Submit>
<input type="reset" value=Reset><br/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The code doesn't validate from the radio button on wards. but if i run the radio button code and the other validation codes after the radio button code it works and when compiled in a single form it doesn't works. the drop down menu validation doesn't works at all. please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the [tag:JSP] code in the [tag:HTML] file?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with your radio button check. In your code, you can use one variable like `x`,  that's the problem. kindly refer below code :

```
if (atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=x.length)
```

That above code `x` variable doesn't declare and doesn't assign any where in your code. So that line error occurred and terminated.

You change this `x` to `email_str`, As per your code should be like below,

```
if (atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=email_str.length)
```

It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should change your on submit Event like below

```
<form name="my_form" onsubmit="return validate(this.form)">
```

Here your complete Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(form)
{
var name_str=document.my_form.name.value;
if((name_str==null)||(name_str==""))
{
    alert("Enter Name")
    return false
    }
var pwd_str=document.my_form.pwd.value;
if((pwd_str=="null")||(pwd_str==""))
    {
    alert("Enter Password")
    return false
    }
var repwd_str=document.my_form.repwd.value;
if((repwd_str=="null")||(repwd_str==""))
    {
    alert("ReEnter Password")
    return false
    }
if(pwd_str!=repwd_str)
{    
    alert("password must be same!");  
    return false  
    }  
var age_str=document.my_form.age.value;
if((age_str=="null")||(age_str==""))
    {
    alert("enter age")
    return false
    }
if (isNaN(age_str))
{
      alert("only numeric")
      return false
}
var ph_str=document.my_form.ph.value;
if((ph_str=="null")||(ph_str==""))
{
alert("enter phone number")
return false
}
if (isNaN(ph_str))
{
      alert("only numeric ph")
      return false
}
if((ph_str.length<1)||(ph_str.length>10))
    {
    alert("Invalid length of ph")
    return false
    }
var email_str=document.my_form.email.value;
if((email_str=="null")||(email_str==""))
{
alert("enter email")
return false
}
var email = document.getElementById('mail');
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
alert('Please provide a valid email address');
email.focus;
return false;
}
var gender=document.my_form.gender.value;
if((gender=="null")||(gender=="")){
   alert("Please Select Gender");
   return false;
}
var i;
var group1 = document.my_form.hobby;
for (var i=0; i<group1.length; i++) {
if (group1[i].checked)
break;
}
if (i==group1.length){
    alert("No box is checked"); 
    return false;
}
var country=document.my_form.mymenu.value;
if(country=='Select'){
   alert("You must Select your Country");
   return false;
}
}   
</script>
```